# Join array with multiple whitespaces

Tags: ruby, arrays, whitespace

I have an array `["hello", "there", "buddy"]` and I want to join these strings together. The issue is that I want to join them together with multiple white-spaces, specifically three of them. My code runs as

```
sentence = sentence.join("   ")
```

However, instead of returning

```
hello   there   buddy
```

it returns as

```
hello there buddy
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it HTML where the spaces are "missing"?

Comment: The text is within a li tag. The page source shows `<li>Hello there buddy</li>`

Comment: Seems like something's cleaning up the data before it's inserted, if the value is exactly that in the database, or after retrieval. What if you join with `join("SPACESPACESPACE")` instead?

Comment: Nothing is cleaning up the data. Browsers collapse multiple whitespace between words into a single space, which is what is happening inside `<li>word   word   word</li>`. To display multiple spaces, a non-whitespace character has to be used, such as `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The text is within a li tag. The page source shows
>
> Hello there buddy

The problem is that browsers collapse whitespace runs between words. You can see this, and counter it, a couple ways.

```
<p>1   2   3</p>
```

displays with multiple spaces here on Stack Overflow, and consequently your browser, because I told it to use code formatting. I can do it also with:

```
1   2   3
```

which tells the browser to display using `<pre>` formatting, which, again, is a fixed-width font which respects the whitespaces.

If you don't use a fixed-width format designed to preserve whitespace, you have to get tricky.

In HTML you can use a non-breaking space:

1   2   3

which, in HTML looks like:

```
1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3
```

If I'd used regular whitespace it would look like:

1   2   3

There are CSS games that can be played too, but using `&nbsp;` is probably the most common.

To try this at home, save the following to a file called "test.html" and open it with your browser:

```
<html><body><p>collapsed    whitespaces   here</p>
<p>non-breaking&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;spaces&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;here</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. Although steenslag gave me the correct answer, you were able to explain the exact cause of my problem. Hence, why I gave you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It just works as expected:

```
p ["hello", "there", "buddy"].join("   ")
# => "hello   there   buddy"
```

Comment: I'm starting to think that it may be a database issue. I'm using DataMapper and Sinatra. Let me do a little more investigation and research this, then I'll update my question.

Comment: I'll accept the answer since the issue seems unrelated to my question.

Comment: It's not the database, it's how browsers work. If you need to display multiple spaces, you'll have to use `&nbsp;` instead of `' '` to join your words.